# In Angularjs application add ngdisabled=true dnamically to an element in the controller

Tags: jquery, angularjs, angularjs-directive, jqlite

In  my AngularJs application I have my html as shown below:

```
<div id="myDIV">
  <div class = "myClass">
     <a class="first my-ctrl" ng-click="update()"> </a>
 </div>
</div>
```

Now, I need to add `ng-disabled="true"` to the above anchor tag on some model watch in my controller, some thing like.

```
$scope.$watch('myVal', function (){
  // Add ng-diabled to above anchor i.e., (<a class="first my-ctrl" ng-click="update()"> </a>)
});
```

the tricky part of it is, I don't have direct access to the above html. I am using another directive and that directive has the above html inside it. So in my controller, I need to access the anchor element using query selector and then add `ng-disabled="true"` to that anchor element through my controller.  How can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a suggestion inspired by Bootstrap3. If you take a look into [the code](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha/css/bootstrap.css), you'll see some classes that are used to present and manipulate buttons with `btn` and `disabled` classes:

```
.btn.disabled,
.btn:disabled,
fieldset[disabled] .btn {
  cursor: not-allowed;
  opacity: .65;
}
```

but also it's possible to apply `btn` and `disabled` classes to an anchor element:

```
a.btn.disaabled,
fieldset[disabled] a.btn {
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

An anchor presented as

```
<a class="btn btn-default disabled">I am a button</a>
```

has these computed CSS properties, according to what Safari provides:

```
-webkit-user-select: none;
background-color: rgb(92, 184, 92);
border-bottom-color: rgb(92, 184, 92);
border-bottom-left-radius: 4px;
border-bottom-right-radius: 4px;
border-bottom-style: solid;
border-bottom-width: 1px;
border-left-color: rgb(92, 184, 92);
border-left-style: solid;
border-left-width: 1px;
border-right-color: rgb(92, 184, 92);
border-right-style: solid;
border-right-width: 1px;
border-top-color: rgb(92, 184, 92);
border-top-left-radius: 4px;
border-top-right-radius: 4px;
border-top-style: solid;
border-top-width: 1px;
box-sizing: border-box;
color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
cursor: not-allowed;
display: inline-block;
font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
font-size: 16px;
font-weight: normal;
height: 38px;
line-height: 24px;
opacity: 0.6499999761581421;
padding-bottom: 6px;
padding-left: 16px;
padding-right: 16px;
padding-top: 6px;
text-align: center;
text-decoration: none;
vertical-align: middle;
white-space: nowrap;
width: 111.671875px;
```

The ones you actually need are

- `-webkit-user-select`,
- `cursor`, which is most relevant, and
- `opacity`, just to make it look like disabled.

Applying them, you can be sure your anchor element will behave *exactly* like a button. Therefore, this may be a solution to your problem.

So, what you do next?

1. Employ [`ng-class`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass). Add/remove class `disabled` when necessary.
2. Add some CSS to make your anchor element behave like it's a button.
3. Bind it to `ng-click` if necessary.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

[Edited]
What you can do here since it's an anchor and it cannot takes a ng-disabled (Thank you @skubski) is doing it in css with a ng-class.

something like :

```
<a class="first my-ctrl" ng-click="update() ng-class="{'disabled' : yourCondition}"> </a>

a.disabled { 
    color: #AAAAAA; 
    cursor: default; 
    pointer-events: none; 
    text-decoration: none; 
}
```

Comment: Form controls have a disabled property on them but anchor tags do not. Therefore, ng-disabled has nothing to actually pin itself on thus rendering this useless code!

Comment: Oh sorry, then I'd do this in css with a ng-class, somthing like : a.disabled {
    color: #AAAAAA;
    cursor: default;
    pointer-events: none;
    text-decoration: none;
}

Comment: Please update your answer accordingly! :-) @ThibaudL

Answer (score 0):

Form controls have a disabled property on them but [anchor](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_a.asp) tags do not. Therefore, [ng-disabled](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngDisabled) has nothing to actually pin itself on. If you insist on using the ng-disabled directive you can use a button and restyle it. Or you'll need to rethink how to 'disable' the anchor, which is described in the other answer.

You can test it yourself and act according your needs/requirements. This small example shows it. ([Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/9F06iudIM7d72VUWk0YD?p=preview))

HTML

```
  <div class="well" ng-controller="TestController">
    <h4>Type x to toggle ng-disabled: <input type="text" ng-model="test"></h4>
    <a class="btn btn-primary" 
       ng-disabled="test == 'x'" 
       ng-click="handleAnchorClick()">ANCHOR</a>
    <button class="btn btn-primary" 
            ng-disabled="test == 'x'" 
            ng-click="handleButtonClick()">BUTTON</button>
    <hr/>
    <p>Anchor Clicks: {{anchorClicks}}</p>
    <p>Button Clicks: {{buttonClicks}}</p>
  </div>
```

Controller

```
function TestController($scope) {
    $scope.test = '';
    $scope.anchorClicks = 0;
    $scope.buttonClicks = 0;
    $scope.handleAnchorClick = function() {
        $scope.anchorClicks++;
    };
    $scope.handleButtonClick = function() {
        $scope.buttonClicks++;
    };

}
```

CSS

```
button {
        /*Reset's every elements apperance*/
        background: none repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
        border: medium none;
        border-spacing: 0;
        color: #26589F;
        font-family: 'PT Sans Narrow',sans-serif;
        font-size: 16px;
        font-weight: normal;
        line-height: 1.42rem;
        list-style: none outside none;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        text-align: left;
        text-decoration: none;
        text-indent: 0;
}
```